# Why this keyword in a method

Tags: javascript, this, ecmascript-5

I know the question is quite dumb.

The relevant code:

```
var myObj = {
   name: 'Popo',
   lastName: 'Shomo',
   fullName: function(){
      return name + " " + lastName;
   }
};
```

I know by adding `this.name` and `this.lastName` it will work, but my question is: why can't it go to its lexical scope and grab the properties from there? I know its totally D-U-M-B but I wanted to know the proper reason behind it.

Comment: If you didn't originally include a `name` property and set one as `myObj.name = 'Popo'` afterwards, would `name` still refer to `this.name` inside that function? It's potentially confusing scoping issues that make `this` a much simpler solution (and why [the `with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) is deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can theoretically have a variable in your file and object properties with the same name. Object properties always have to come from a set object, otherwise every object oriented language will look for a previously set variable.